# How to stop fscanf() from duplicating values?

Tags: c, scanf

```
char hexe;
int hex1;
FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen("address01", "r");

while (fscanf(pFile,"%c %d",&hexe, &hex1) != EOF) { //ERROR likely here

printf("%c %d", hexe, hex1);                        //ERROR likely here 

}
```

My address01 file:

```
10
20
22
18
E10
210
12
```

It is printing 18 and 12 twice. Why those numbers and how do I get it to act normal?

(Additionally, I want to be able to read E10. This could be the reason for the issue? I am unsure).

Comment: You should not be comparing `fscanf()`'s return value to `EOF`. Re-read the documentation for the function to see what it rerurns and when.

Comment: You should include both your actual and expected output, btw.

Comment: If you want to read hex, use `%x` instead of `%d`.  But — be aware that `%x` will read `10` as decimal 16, not decimal 10.  You could try `%i`, but that requires a `0x` or `0X` prefix to identify hexadecimal input (and would treat a leading zero as indicating octal input).  You should probably capture and test the result of `fscanf()` more thoroughly.  Your first call to `fscanf()` should end up with `printf()` printing `1 0` instead of `10` because the `%c` eats the `1` leaving the `0` for the `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to read hex, use `%x` instead of `%d`.  But — be aware that `%x` will read `10` as decimal 16, not decimal 10.  You could try `%i`, but that requires a `0x` or `0X` prefix to identify hexadecimal input (and would treat a leading zero as indicating octal input).

You should probably capture and test the result of `fscanf()` more thoroughly.  If you get EOF, so be it; but you might get 1 or 2.  (In some situations, you could get 0, but with `%c` as the first conversion specification, you won't get 0 for a result).

Your first call to `fscanf()` should end up with `printf()` printing `1 0` instead of `10` because the `%c` eats the `1` leaving the `0` for the `%d`.

Subsequent calls have the `%c` capturing the newline `\n`, and then the number.

After you read `18`, the next `fscanf()` returns `1` and has the newline after the `18` in `hexe`, but it fails to convert the `E` into a decimal number, so `18` is left in `hex1` and it is printed twice.  The next call places `E` into `hexe` and `10` into `hex1`, so you see `18E 10` in the output.

The argument is similar for why you get `12` twice.  There's a newline after the `12`.  Again, the `%c` captures the newline and then the `%d` conversion would fail (because `fscanf()` encounters EOF, but it has made one successful conversion, so it doesn't report EOF yet).  So `hex1` still contains `12`, and `12` would therefore be printed twice.

Comment: well.... now I know why... what's the best course to correct it tho so it works properly?

Comment: The second paragraph outlines what you need to do. You need to decide what behaviour you want on the first line of input.   You need to specify what should happen with the `E10` line and variants such as `1E0` and `Z00` (which is obviously not hex).   When the requirements are specified, you can write the code.  Think seriously about using `fgets()` to read the line of data and then use `sscanf()` to parse it. That way, you can parse the line different ways if the first attempt doesn’t work.